# Creating a list from table values in Spreadsheet/Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some data in tabular form and based on tables values, I need to create a list using corresponding Row and Column headers

[image]

So, as seen in table, Number 1 is at intersection of City1 and Item1, so I want City1_Item1 in the output list. Similarly 2 is at intersection of City2, Item2 and also at City3, Item3, so I want City2_Item2_City3_Item3 as another item in the output list.

Comment: hurm.. mind sharing the [details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) of method you had tried ?

Comment: `=INDEX($A$1:$F$1,AGGREGATE(14,6,(IF($B$2:$F$7=$A10,COLUMN($B$2:$F$7))),SEQUENCE(1,SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$F$7=$A10)))))&"_"&INDEX($A$1:$A$7,AGGREGATE(14,6,(IF($B$2:$F$7=$A10,ROW($B$2:$F$7))),SEQUENCE(1,SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$F$7=$A10)))))` not sure if it counts, since it spills the combinations to the right instead of combining them. ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgrbl.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

In `B10`, array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) copied down :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCAT(IF(B$2:F$7=A10,A$2:A$7,"")&" "&IF(B$2:F$7=A10,B$1:F$1,"")&" "))," ","_")
```

[image]